# Where is the right place to implement weak and synchronized .NET delegates?

Tags: .net, delegates

When implementing the weak-reference and/or thread synchronization pattern for delegates, are there guidelines and or anti-patterns as to where the logic should be implemented?

Consider that the class *WindowA* wants to subscribe to an event on *DataB*, where *DataB* is a long-lived instance which is modified on many (non-UI threads).

The options for implementing weak, synchronized events are:

- Option 1: When *WindowA* attaches a delegate to the custom event on *DataB*, the cusom event logic checks SynchronizationContext.Current for the calling thread, and stores this so that later, when the event is raised, the delegate can be invoked via the SynchronizationContext.       or:
- Option 2: *WindowA* implements *ProxyC*, which acts as a target for *DataB*. Target methods on *ProxyC* implement synchronization and weak referencing logic, and forwards invocations to methods on *WindowA*.  *WindowA* is able to be garbage collected, but *ProxyC* must dettach itself from all events before it can be garbage collected.  or:
- Option 3: *WindowA* uses delegate conversion utilities (like those from in [SharpObservation](http://sharpobservation.codeplex.com)) to make the delegates weak and synchronized before attaching them to events on *DataB*. 
  i.e.:

  DataB.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(WindowA.HandlePropertyChanged).MakeWeak()

First off... is there any merit to Option 1? While it's a convenient place to implement to weak reference and sync logic, it seems to break the single-responsibility pattern to force a data object to become aware of synchronization and referencing semantics.

Option 2 seems nice and clean. I like it in every way except for the fact that it involves the extra work of creating an extra class to handle the weak referencing. Even so, you get a memory leak unless the proxy knows how to remove the delegates that are targeting it.

Option 3 allows the delegates themselves to carry the responsibility of synchronization and weak referencing, but has the draw-back that the utility methods must be invoked by the code attaching the events. As far as I know, most UI data-binding technologies don't allow you to control how the data binding attaches to events on *DataB* (hence the alure of option 1).

**The BIG question...** Is there a one-size-fits-all pattern to be had here? Is there a single, better-than-all-others pattern?